# Issues reading floats from .txt file

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a .txt file with some floats into my code.
I wrote a sample code just to tackle the issue outside my main code and I am using the following floats to test it:

```
10.8f  
100.8f
-10.8f
```

The issue I am running into is that the code only reads in the first float properly and displays it but all the other floats following it do not look correct:

```
10.8
0
4.57874e-41
```

Code:

```
#include<fstream>                                                     
#include<iostream>                                                    
#include <vector>                                                     
#include <string>                                                     
#include <iomanip>                                                    
using namespace std; 

int main()                                                            
{                                                                                                                       
  float Cam1,Cam2,Cam3;                                               
                                                                      
  string path = "sample.txt"; //Text file with above mentioned floats                                        
  ifstream fin;                                                       
                                                                      
  fin.open(path);                                                     
  if(fin.is_open())                                                   
    {                                                                                                              
      fin >> Cam1;                                                    
      fin >> Cam2;                                                    
      fin >> Cam3;                                                    
      fin.close();                                                    
    }                                                                 
                                                                      
  cout << Cam1 << '\n';                                               
  cout << Cam2 << '\n';                                               
  cout << Cam3 << '\n';                                               
}
```

I really am confused as to why it reads the first properly but not the others, it works when I change the values as well, the above is just one example case. I am fairly new to C++ so any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: `f` is not part of the format of a number in text representation. It is difficult to do a correct reading for that file, you have to read the numbers one by one and clearing (reseting) the error mode of the stream each time. If you can remove the `f`s from the file, they are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks that actually worked! I thought I had tried that before but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `f` suffix is valid in C++ code, but not in input text parsed by `istream`. It's useful in code to distinguish between `float` and `double` constants, but user input doesn't control variable data types.

Comment: Yes the other comment also said something similar. Taking the 'f's out made it work. The code I am working on had the `f` suffix and I thought I needed it in the user input. Thank you for your reply!